# Pretty-print for shell script

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, indentation

I'm looking for something similiar to [indent](http://linux.die.net/man/1/indent) but for (bash) scripts. Console only, no colorizing, etc.

Do you know of one ?

Comment: Also consider putting your answers in [this more general question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923301/what-applications-do-you-know-of-that-can-reformat-code)

Comment: I wrote a [script](https://gist.github.com/lucgagan/9f4219058f89c9d003ceced6d1d544b3) that does the exact thing. Here is a demo https://ray.run/tools/bash-command-formatter

Answer (score 7):

Vim can indent bash scripts. But not reformat them before indenting.
Backup your bash script, open it with vim, type `gg=GZZ` and indent will be corrected.  (Note for the impatient: this overwrites the file, so be sure to do that backup!)

Though, some bugs with `<<` (expecting EOF as first character on a line) *e.g.*

EDIT: ZZ not ZQ

Comment: Backing up with `cp -p $script{,.$(date -Is)}` leaves one with a file that one can `diff -cw` against, showing that this solution works well against a reasonably-complex shell script I tested it against.  (no `<<` here text, though)

Answer (score 3):

In bash I do this:

```
reindent() {
source <(echo "Zibri () {";cat "$1"; echo "}")
declare -f Zibri|head --lines=-1|tail --lines=+3 | sed -e "s/^\s\s\s\s//"
}
```

this eliminates comments and reindents the script "bash way".

If you have HEREDOCS in your script, they got ruined by the sed in the previous function.

So use:

```
reindent() {
source <(echo "Zibri () {";cat "$1"; echo "}")
declare -f Zibri|head --lines=-1|tail --lines=+3"
}
```

But all your script will have a 4 spaces indentation.

Or you can do:

```
reindent () 
{ 
    rstr=$(mktemp -u "XXXXXXXXXX");
    source <(echo "Zibri () {";cat "$1"|sed -e "s/^\s\s\s\s/$rstr/"; echo "}");
    echo '#!/bin/bash';
    declare -f Zibri | head --lines=-1 | tail --lines=+3 | sed -e "s/^\s\s\s\s//;s/$rstr/    /"
}
```

which takes care also of heredocs.

Comment: some tr implementations don't like straight urandom... cat /dev/urandom | base64 can substitute well enough.. thanks

Comment: The last one does not work for me, bash complains. Also, empty lines are lost.

Comment: yes empty lines are lost.. but can be modified for that... i didn't need it.

Comment: you can do another ``tr "\n\n" "ZZ"`` before and after ``tr "ZZ" "\n\n"`` (but there are a million ways)

Comment: @BrianChrisman or you can just type a static random string... it just must not be present in the code... I used a random one so reindent can reindent itself :D

Answer (score 3):

bash5+ has a --pretty-print option.. it will remove comments though, including a first-line '#!/bin...'

Answer (score 1):

[shfmt](https://github.com/mvdan/sh) works very well.

You can format bash scripts and also check the formatting from pre-commit hooks.

```
# reformat
shfmt -l -w script.sh

# check if the formatting is OK
shfmt -d script.sh

# works on the whole directory as well
shfmt -l -w .
```

The only option absent is that it does not reformat according to line length ([yet](https://github.com/mvdan/sh/issues/80)).

Since it is written in go you can just download the binary for most platforms, e.g. for Travis (`.travis.yml`):

```
install:
  - curl -LsS -o ~/shfmt https://github.com/mvdan/sh/releases/download/v3.1.2/shfmt_v3.1.2_linux_amd64
  - chmod +x ~/shfmt
script:
  - ~/shfmt -d .
```

There is also a cross compiled js version on npm and a lot of editor plugins (see [related projects](https://github.com/mvdan/sh#related-projects))